# Render/ Preview Image from URL input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution to render image before uploading via input URL.

[image]

**My code**

```
<input name="thumbnail" placeholder="Post image URL here" />
```

I've been trying methods [like this](http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit). Adding `onchange="readURL(this);"` to above mentioned code does nothing. It appears they only work with local files only.

Comment: Do you also have an `<img>` tag, like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/2231440)?

Comment: Fully working snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56798296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the value of the input as the source for an image tag. You can hide and show the image tag, create a new image each time, wait for the load event and show a spinner, use a default image, the possibilities are endless.

```
$('[name="thumbnail"]').on('change', function() {
     $('img.preview').prop('src', this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EFkW2/)

Comment: Thanks, I tested it both at Chrome and Firefox. Its working smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You could use canvas.

```
var oCanvas = doc.getElementById('imgThumb'),
    oContext = oCanvas.getContext('2d');

oContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
```

Try out my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aliasm2k/tAum2/